# Field `lyrics` is empty for MPMediaItem of the current playing song in swift, ios 12+

Tags: ios, swift, mpmediaitem

I have the similar problem like:

- [How do I get the lyrics of the currently playing song in Swift 4?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54042020/how-do-i-get-the-lyrics-of-the-currently-playing-song-in-swift-4) - there is no answer here
- [iPhone song lyrics access](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6357436/iphone-song-lyrics-access) - answer does not work
- [How to get lyrics for Now Playing song in iOS10 (Swift 3)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43222995/how-to-get-lyrics-for-now-playing-song-in-ios10-swift-3) - answer does not work

I need to get lyrics for current playing song.

I get empty result if I simply try to get lyrics from a media item:

```
let musicPlayerController = MPMusicPlayerController.systemMusicPlayer

// ...

if let nowPlayingItem = musicPlayerController.nowPlayingItem {
    // We have empty string here
    if let lyrics = nowPlayingItem.lyrics {
        print("Lyrics: \(lyrics)")
    }
}
```

I've tried to get lyrics through asset url as suggested in answers above, but it does not work, asset url is always nil.

```
let musicPlayerController = MPMusicPlayerController.systemMusicPlayer

// ...

if let nowPlayingItem = musicPlayerController.nowPlayingItem {
    if let songUrl = nowPlayingItem.value(forProperty: MPMediaItemPropertyAssetURL) as? URL {
        print("song url: \(songUrl)")
        let songAsset = AVURLAsset(url: songUrl)

        if let lyricsFromAsset = songAsset.lyrics {
            print("Lyrics from asset: \(lyricsFromAsset)")
        }
    }
}
```

I've also tried without any success (also get nil and empty string accordingly):

```
print("asset url: \(nowPlayingItem.assetURL)")
print("lyrics from value for property: \(nowPlayingItem.value(forProperty: MPMediaItemPropertyLyrics))")
```

I know exactly that the song has lyrics because I see it in Apple Music app on iPhone for the song. I've tried to get lyrics for the song: Queen - Bohemian Rhapsody.

Can somebody help with getting lyrics for current playing song from apple music?

Comment: I faced the same issue you got any solution?

Answer (score 0):

Are we talking about local files here? I am not sure how it works with Apple Music files, but for local files this method has 100% success rate in retrieving lyrics.

```
extension MPMediaItem {
    func lyrics() -> String? {
        guard let url = assetURL else { return nil }
        let ass = AVAsset(url: url)
        return ass.lyrics
    }
}
```

Comment: This method not working with local files. Is there any other solution?